# Finding the derivative of $a^{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus

I have a question on finding the derivative of $a^{f(x)}$ where $a$ is a constant and $x$ is the variable that we want to differentiate w.r.t.

**UPDATE**

I got it!

$$
\begin{align*}a^{f(x)}  &= e^{log(a)f(x)}\\\therefore \frac{d}{dx} e^{log(a)f(x)}&=e^{log(a)f(x)}\begin{bmatrix}log(a)f'(x)\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You probably wanted to ask a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $a=e^{\log a}$, and so $a^{f(x)} = e^{(\log a)f(x)}$; apply the chain rule.

Comment: I finally saw the light! Question: Can I change it to $f(x)log(a)$ and then perform the differentiation?

Comment: What do you mean by 'change it'? It's certainly true that $(\log a)f(x) = f(x)\log(a)$, if that's what you're asking - they're two equivalent ways of writing the same thing. I just wrote it like I did to emphasise that $\log(a)$ is constant, so doesn't contribute to the derivative in any interesting way.

Comment: I got your answer. Could you assist to check the Update?

Comment: That's not quite correct; the first $\log (a) f(x)$ shouldn't be there. In general, the derivative of $e^{g(x)}$ is $g'(x)e^{g(x)}$ by the chain rule; apply this here with $g(x)=\log(a)f(x)$.

Comment: I think I have made the necessary changes.

Comment: That's right :)

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dx}(a^{f(x)}) = a^{f(x)}\ln a\cdot f'(x)$